# SQL SERVER: one result for each id in multiple result set

Tags: sql-server

Below is my table schema:-

```
Appointments
-------------------------------------------------
|apptID| persID| apptDate| apptCode| apptConfirm|
-------------------------------------------------
```

The above table records all the appointments ever made. 
I want to get a result set where if the apptCode is "200" then get the previous appointment of the person .

I tried the below query

```
WITH selected_person AS
(SELECT persID, apptDate FROM Appointments WHERE apptCode IN ('200'))

SELECT apptID, apptDate, apptCode 
FROM selected_person sp LEFT JOIN Appointments ap ON sp.persID = ap.persID 
WHERE ap.apptDate < sp.apptDate
```

The above queries gets me the previous appointments but I only want one result which is previous appointment to the one which has apptCode '200'

I dont know how LIMIT will help in this scenario.
Any pointers will be really appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You can group by `sp.persID`, get the MAX(apptDate), and order by apptDate desc.

Comment: You could look at the lag/lead functions that were introduced in SQL Server 2012. The other option is to use row numbers and join back to n -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give each previous appointment an index with a window function and then take the 1st one, something like this:

```
WITH selected_person AS (
    SELECT persID, apptDate FROM Appointments WHERE apptCode IN ('200')
), previous_appointment AS (
    SELECT ap.apptID, ap.apptDate, ap.apptCode, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ap.persID ORDER BY ap.apptDate DESC) ix
    FROM selected_person sp 
    LEFT JOIN Appointments ap ON sp.persID = ap.persID 
    WHERE ap.apptDate < sp.apptDate
)
SELECT apptID, apptDate, apptCode 
    FROM previous_appointment
    WHERE ix=1;
```

Comment: Brilliant! this helped :)